# Ejabberd check cipher with openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, erlang, ejabberd

I am trying to set up ciphers for port 5222 ejabberd 14.07
my ejabberd.yml:

I have removed ECDHE and DHE based ciphers

```
port: 5222
module: ejabberd_c2s
protocol_options:
  - "no_sslv2"
  - "no_sslv3"
  - "no_tlsv1"
  - "no_tlsv1_1"
max_stanza_size: 65536 
shaper: c2s_shaper
access: c2s
ciphers: "EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS"
starttls: true
```

And check with openssl:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect dev.my.server:5222 -starttls xmpp
CONNECTED(00000003)
^C
```

Connection accepted (from my server logs):

```
 Accepted connection 10.2.3.1:41007 -> 10.2.3.2:5222
```

But when I run

```
openssl s_client -cipher 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA'  -connect dev.mantu.im:5222 </dev/null -starttls xmpp
```

or -cipher 'DSS' I slill see "Accepted connection", but I am expecting it should fails
What was set up wrong? Or I run uncorrect command to check it?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to configure port 5223 with `tls: true` and then trying to connect without starttls. Without this `Accepted connection` can mean anything, for example connecting without doing SSL magic.

Comment: I set tls:true restart but same results

Answer (score 0):

finally I checked it with this tool [tsp hello dump](https://github.com/ge0rg/tls-hello-dump) and escalus
./tls-hello-dump eth0 | sed -f ./readable.sed > /var/log/ejabberd/tlshello.txt

and found

```
10.2.1.18   10.2.1.44   TLSv1 ClientHello TLSv1.2 :TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256:TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA:TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5:TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV:
10.2.1.44   10.2.1.18   TLSv1.2 ServerHello TLSv1.2 cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

So ServerHello TLSv1.2 cipher TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 always correct cihpers

P.S. I can not remove this posted question